# How to add custom-style dom-element using javascript

Tags: javascript, css, polymer

So in polymer you can add a custom element as the `custom-styles` for your elements.

```
<dom-module id="shared-styles">
     <template>
         <style>
            your styles here
         </style>
     </template>
</dom-module>
```

And then include it using:

```
<style is="custom-style" include="shared-styles"></style>
```

Problem is I am loading this using `async` now to make it a progressive web app.

`<link rel="import" id="bundle" href="{{asset "html/polymer-head.html"}}" async>`

So the `<style` is not working... so I tried the following at the very end of my loading:

`style.setAttribute('is', 'custom-style');
style.setAttribute('include', 'shared-styles');
document.head.appendChild(style);`

But it didn't work.

Anyone knows how to inject that `dom-element` as a `custom-style`?

Comment: That HTML import doesn't look like Polymer syntax (other than the double-curly brackets). Are you using another library/framework for that binding?

Comment: Yeah, that is ghost backend delivering the file, at the end it looks like this `/assets/html/polymer-head.html?v=a60c252bbf`.

Comment: According to the polymer toolbox app and zuperkulblog they use a different more solid design approach for this, so I'll try to emulate those instead of trying this easy on the fly styling changes that sounds cool but it is not really needed.